# AngularJS Service -> Controller population

Tags: angularjs

All over my code I have things like:

```
SearchModel.findAll($scope.report).then(function (xhr) {
    $scope.searchResults= xhr.data;
});
```

is there anyway to just automagically assign the `searchResults` variable to the view after the request is done.  Seems like there should be if not...

Comment: may be in a run block like $rootScope.searchResults= xhr.data;

Comment: Promises are only resolved during a $digest cycle, so this should "automagically" update. Perhaps in the dom you are referring to the wrong `$scope`?

Comment: @hassassin so what would the syntax for the above look like ... it can't be that easy haha.

Comment: it's that easy! wow angular. I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are only resolved during a $digest cycle, so this should "automagically" update.

It really is that easy!

To prove it I made a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QKXf3/) that simulates a server response using a service and assign the data to a scope. The dom will automatically display the data.

```
service.get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Hope this helped!

---

Comment: could you do: $scope.searchResults = SearchModel.findAll($scope.report)

Comment: Yup, promises behave just like the resolved data in the dom. so `$scope.data = service.get();` works exactly the same. Here is that fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/QKXf3/1/

Comment: Currently you can just pass promises to the templates directly, but that feature is deprecated and will be removed with Angular 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a promise that returns an array, you can use a helper function like this:

```
app.factory('PromiseList', function() {
    return function(promise, error) {
        var list = [];
        promise.then(function (result) {
            angular.copy(result, list); # or in your case .copy(result.data, list)
        }, error);
        return list;
    }
});
```

Then in your code, do:

```
$scope.searchResults = PromiseList(SearchModel.findAll($scope.report))
```

You can also use this solution with other kinds of objects, however not with strings or numbers as they are immutable objects in JavaScript.

If you are only developing for an old version of AngularJS (think pre-1.2), you can also just pass the promise to the template and it will be unwrapped automatically.